# Separating two different types with "and"

Tags: grammar, conjunctions

Recently, I read through this sentence in my book.

> Limestone is found in association with rocks composed of calcium carbonates or calcium and magnesium carbonates.

I want to focus on this last part: **calcium and magnesium carbonates**

I thought that this could be two things. Either calcium carbonates and magnesium carbonates, or calcium AND magnesium carbonate.

In most cases, the first meaning would be the appropriate meaning and most would read it that way. What would be a good way to express the second meaning?

Comment: I couldn't think of a better title, so I would welcome suggestions for a better title.

Comment: Limestone is surely a naturally occurring form of calcium carbonate.

Comment: Dolomite is 'an anhydrous carbonate mineral composed of calcium magnesium carbonate, ideally CaMg(CO3)2', according to Wikipedia.

Comment: The only really unambiguous way of expressing the second meaning would be to switch the constituents: “… rocks composed of calcium carbonates or magnesium carbonates and calcium”. Even that is not quite unambiguous, though: is it then (1) rocks composed of (a) calcium carbonates or (b) magnesium carbonates and calcium; or (2) rocks composed of calcium and (a) calcium carbonates or (b) magnesium carbonates? Complete and clumsy unambiguity: “rocks composed of either (a) calcium carbonates; or (b) magnesium carbonates and calcium”.

Comment: Calcium would not exist naturally: it's too reactive.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth True, I just wanted to know how to use in case of similar situations.

Comment: Try 'We found bottles containing lead and iron oxides'.

Comment: Hmmm.  I don't sense a rat.

Comment: *separating* vs *seperating*.

Answer (score 1):

To express the second meaning, I would write:

Limestone is found in association with rocks composed either of calcium carbonates or of magnesium carbonates and calcium.

Comment: But ... there's a ***big*** difference chemically between calcium and calcium carbonate.

Comment: @PeterShor: Expressing the unlikely reading unambiguously is exactly the point of this answer.

Comment: In fact, that's the OP's question, which I didn't read carefully enough.

Answer (score 0):

Structuring the phrases consistently -- making both of them prepositional phrases -- would likely clear the air.

*Limestone is found in association with rocks composed of calcium carbonates or **of** calcium (carbonates?) and magnesium carbonates.*

Answer (score 0):

If you mean "calcium magnesium carbonate", call it that.

If you mean "calcium carbonate and magnesium carbonate", either call them that, or if you wish to shorten it, say "**carbonate of calcium and of magnesium**".  (You could say "carbonates", but some readers might construe this to mean there are multple types of calcium carbonates and/or magnesium carbonates —are there?)

Compare MAALOX, which contains both aluminum hydroxide and magnesium hydroxide. One could say it contains "hydroxide of aluminum and of magnesium"